# How to run python codes (not in views) periodically in Django Framework?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django Framework to write a middleware. Basically, every week, it calls an external API to receive a xml file, does some data processing and sends the results to RabbitMQ.

I am new to Django Framework. I wrote some python files to achieve the logic, but these files did not execute when running the server. I am wondering how to run these codes periodically which are not inside views.

Thank you.

Comment: look for something like running cron jobs with `django` or if you have an advance case, look for using `celery-beat` with `django`.

Comment: In addition to @Abhyudai's comment, you can use `django-q`, `django-crontab`. You can also use celery but it might be overkill if you only want to run simple periodic tasks.